# Validations not being applied during CSV upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

My model has the following:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :batch, :scope => :projectid
```

AND

```
 def self.import(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      Order.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

The csv is uploading and being placed in the database regardless of the validation (I am purposefully trying to insert a record that should violate that validation).  I am not sure why it is being allowed to violate that validation on upload.

Controller:

```
  def import
    Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)
    redirect_to orders_path, :notice => "Orders imported"
  end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_tag import_orders_path, multipart: true do %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= file_field_tag :csv_file, accept: 'csv', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %>    
  <%= submit_tag "Upload Orders", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def self.import(csv_file)
    order = Order.new
    if order.valid? == false
      nil
    else
      CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
        Order.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
```